# Writing function around statistical tests in R

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a function for my (working) R script in order to clean up my code. I do not have experience with writing functions, but decided I should invest some time into this. The goal of my function is to perform multiple statistical tests while only passing the required dataframe, quantitative variable and grouping variable **once**. However, I cannot get this to work. For your reference, I'll use the ToothGrowth data frame to illustrate my problem.

Say I want to run a Kruskal-Wallis test and one-way ANOVA on `len`, to compare different groups named `supp`, for whatever reason. I can do this separately with

```
kruskal.test(len ~ supp, data = ToothGrowth)
aov(len ~ supp, data = ToothGrowth)
```

Now I want to write a function that performs both tests. This is what I had thought should work:

```
stat_test <- function(mydata, quantvar, groupvar) {
  kruskal.test(quantvar ~ groupvar, data = mydata)
  aov(quantvar ~ groupvar, data = mydata)
}
```

But if I then run `stat_test(ToothGrowth, "len", "sup")`, I get the error

```
Error in kruskal.test.default("len", "supp") : 
  all observations are in the same group
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a nice first question which gives an example of what you've tried so far and the specific error you've run into. One way to write an even better question is to provide a small subset of your data so that we can reproduce your error without having to guess at what your data look like. You can use something like `dput(head(mydata, 10))` to get the first ten rows.

Comment: @qdread `ToothGrowth` is given in the example. This is a built-in data set in R. But I agree with your sentiment that this is a good first question.

Comment: Good point, I did not notice that. So it's definitely a great first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `deparse(substitute(quantvar))` to get the quoted name of the column you are passing to the function, and this will allow you to build a formula using `paste`. This is a more idiomatic way of operating in R.

Here's a reproducible example:

```r
stat_test <- function(mydata, quantvar, groupvar) {
  A <- as.formula(paste(deparse(substitute(quantvar)), "~", 
                        deparse(substitute(groupvar))))
  print(kruskal.test(A, data = mydata))
  cat("\n--------------------------------------\n\n")
  aov(A, data = mydata)
}

stat_test(ToothGrowth, len, supp)
#> 
#>  Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
#> 
#> data:  len by supp
#> Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 3.4454, df = 1, p-value = 0.06343
#> 
#> 
#> --------------------------------------
#> Call:
#>    aov(formula = A, data = mydata)
#> 
#> Terms:
#>                     supp Residuals
#> Sum of Squares   205.350  3246.859
#> Deg. of Freedom        1        58
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 7.482001
#> Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for explaining the use of `deparse(substitute())` here! I did not know about this and will apply it to my future scripts.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to convert your variable arguments, given as text strings, into a formula. You can do this by concatenating the strings with `paste()`. Also, you will need to wrap `print()` around both of your statistical tests within the function, otherwise only the last one will display.

Here is the modified function:

```
stat_test <- function(mydata, quantvar, groupvar) {
  model_formula <- formula(paste(quantvar, '~', groupvar))
  print(kruskal.test(model_formula, data = mydata))
  print(aov(model_formula, data = mydata))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I accepted Allan Cameron's answer due to his explanation of `deparse(substitute())`, but yours was also helpful.

Comment: Note that `deparse(substitute())` isn't strictly necessary here since `formula()` will take the quoted variable names (strings) directly as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, if using rstatix (tidy version of statistical functions), you need to use `sym` and `!!`, while using `formula()` when needed.

```
make_kruskal_test <- function(data, quantvar, groupvar) {
  library(rstatix, quietly = TRUE)
  library(rlang, quietly = TRUE)

  formula_expression <- formula(paste(quantvar, "~", groupvar))
  quantvar_sym <- sym(quantvar)

  shapiro <- shapiro_test(data, !!quantvar_sym) %>% print()
}

sample_data <- tibble::tibble(sample = letters[1:5], mean = 1:5)

make_kruskal_test(sample_data, "mean", "sample")

#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   variable statistic     p
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 mean         0.987 0.967
```